# Rxjs Interval request should not reset if still ongoing, but should reset if user changes input

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable, which combines an interval and a date selection action. I use a `combineLatest` and `switchMap` to make a request with these two observables. The idea is the user is looking at a table for a specific date (which can be changed at any time), and that table should be updated every 20 seconds (this time is configurable by the user).

```
data$ = combineLatest(
    this.refreshInterval$,
    this.dateSelected$
).pipe(
    switchMap(([_, date]) => this.requestDataForDate(date))
);
```

This works, except in the case where the request takes longer than 20 seconds. If the request is taking a long time, then every time the interval is triggered, it will cancel the ongoing request and make a new one. This makes sense because I am using a `switchMap`, if I change to a `concatMap` then this won't happen.

However, if the user changes the date, another request should be made and the previous one should be cancelled, which won't happen when using a `concatMap`.

How can I achieve both of these? The request should resubmit if user changes the date, no matter what, but it should not resubmit if the interval is triggered while a request is ongoing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dateSelected$`as base you could:

- first `switch` to the `refreshInterval$`
- and then `exhaust|concat` the interval to the request

  ```
  data$ = this.dateSelected$.pipe(
    switchMap((date) => 
      this.refreshInterval$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.requestDataForDate(date)))
    )
  );
  ```

Comment: I might be wrong, but that would not execute the request immediately, only emitting once the refreshInterval$ emitted again. In this case a new interval observable should be created. Benefit: The timer also starts again once the date changes

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm you're totally right. But I'd assumed that he/she's using a interval that emits right away on subscription(ie. `timer(0,interval)`). Otherwise in his/her original example would also have to wait for the interval to trigger the first data request.

Comment: Yes, you're correct @akotech, I was using a timer that emits straight away, so your solution works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in one stream tbh.

Best I could think of is to create 2 streams and next the result into a subject.

```
data$ = dataSubject.asObservable();

this.refreshInterval$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.dateSelected$)
  exhaustMap(([_, date]) => this.requestDataForDate(date)),
  // some unsubscription
).subscribe(data => dataSubject.next(data));

this.dateSelected$.pipe(
  switchMap(date => this.requestDataForDate(date)),
  // some unsubscription
).subscribe(data => dataSubject.next(data));
```